# How to Create 2 different objects at the same time in 1 view in django rest_framework? DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What I want to do is, create `user` object and `staffprofile` object at the same time. And `username` will be based on `first_name` field and `last_name` field on the `staffprofile` object that is created along with it. And `password` will be auto generated using random module.

I have a custom  `User` model which inherits `AbstractUser` and has these parameters:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name = 'Student')
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name= 'Staff')
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name='Teacher')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False, verbose_name= 'Administrator')
    is_registrar = models.BooleanField (default = False, verbose_name= 'Registrar')

    email = models.EmailField(
    max_length=254,
    unique=True,
    verbose_name='Email Address',
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

and I have a `StaffProfile` model which is related to `User` model through `user` attribute:

```
class StaffProfile(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = [
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),

    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(
            User,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
            primary_key= True,
            limit_choices_to= Q(is_staff= True),
            related_name= 'staffprofile',
        )
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length= 70,)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=70,)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=70,)
    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length= 6,
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
        default='Male',
        )
    employee_number= models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length= 15)
    address= models.TextField()

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Return the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def __str__(self):
        full_name = self.get_full_name()
        return full_name.strip()
```

Is it possible to do it in views.py like this?
(I am not yet writing this down because Im not yet sure. I know this is wrong and also I want to know if my idea is wrong also, or whether should I do the logic on serializers.py instead of views.py. Or maybe use `serializers.Serializer` instead of `serialiazers.ModelSerializer`. )

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createuserandprofile(request):
   userserializer = CreateUserSerializer(data= request.data)
   profileserializer = CreateProfileSerializer(data= request.data)

   if userserializer.is_valid() and profileserializer.is_valid():
        validated_data = profileserializer.validated_data
        firstname = validated_data.get('first_name')
        lastname = validated_data.get('last_name')
        #a function I wrote to concatenate first_name and last_name
        username = generate_username(firstname, lastname)
        #a function I wrote to generate random password
        password = generate_password()
        user = User.objects.create(username=username, password=password, and so on...)
        user.save()
        profileserializer.save(user= user)
        
        #I am not sure what to return
        return Response(...)
```

and maybe do something like this on serializers.py:

```
class CreateUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = '__all__'


class CreateProfileSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
         model = StaffProfile
         fields= '__all__'
         depth = 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution isn't terrible. Don't be shy about it, especially if you are just starting out. I'd recommend to look into generic views as well as they can make your life much easier.

I'd like to show you that there is more than just one solution that achieves this and I don't think that any of them can be labelled as *the best one* for every single project out there.

**Solution 1.** Write your own `ModelSerializer.save`

I'd recommend you to start by reading this article: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers. It shows an example how to implement a writable nested serializer in DRF.

**Solution 2.** Use a 3rd party package

With bare DRF you will need to implement the create method yourself but there are also packages that just work out of the box for simple nested serializers (https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested).

**Solution 3.** Use a plain `serializers.Serializer`

This is a solution that I would recommend only for large applications where `ModelSerializer` can become a limiting factor. Some enterprise-level projects introduce a *service layer*. You can think of a service as a function that encapsulates a portion of the business logic. Invoking such a function could be done in such a way: `user = create_user_service(**serializer.validated_data)`.

This way the business logic can be tested independently from the REST API. Services can also call other services without the necessity of creating a ModelSerializer along the way.

This solution requirest the largest effort of all, as you would need to define serializer fields yourself and ensure that they match the constraints enforced in the model fields.

**Final notes**

I would recommend you to wrap the whole logic with `transaction.atomic()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly). It makes sure that either both or none `Staff` and `User` objects get created.

As a reviewer, I would be fine with either of those variants I would choose the solution that would best fit the existing project architecture but also ensure data integrity at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I will try to do it with class based view(although class based views confuse me a lot). However, I have one more question for you, what would be the difference if I inherit generic class based view in my views.py  instead of APIView?

Comment: Have a look at [an example Generic view](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/71e6c30034a1dd35a39ca74f86c371713e762c79/rest_framework/generics.py). It inherits from `CreateModelMixin` that is implementing a lot of boilerplate logic that you would need to repeat hundreds of times while implementing endpoints using a bare APIView. Please also have a look at how DRF is raising ValidationError (`serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)`) rather than using an if statement. You should start with generic views and write custom code when you get the hang of DRF inner logic